# How far will the person come about when she walks x minutes?

Tags: calculus

A figure shows the footprints of a walking person with a step length of 0.7 m. How can we calculate how far the person comes about when she walks x minutes. How could we do that?

Do we have enough information to do that?

We have that a child with step length 0,30m walks for 30 min.

The possible answers are:

A) $0,7 m \times 50 \times x$

B) $0.7 m \times 100 \times x$

C) $0,7 m \times 400 \times x$

D) $0,7 m \times 4000 \times x$

Comment: We would need the pace as well, i.e. how many steps does the person take per minute. It's something you can tell with some confidence of your good at reading tracks, and the are standard rates given the size of a person, but I know neither of them.

Comment: You need something that links steps and time if you want to get anywhere.

Comment: Is there a relationship between how fast a person can walk and how fast a child can walk? Unless the "person" and "child" walk at the same rate of change? In other words, the constant of proportionality is $1$?

Comment: Possibilities C and D can be eliminated because 400 steps a minute is in the range of a run speed and 4000 steps per minute is faster than a cheetah running away from a ghost.

Comment: I see! Can we eliminate also one of the A or B? Or do we not have enough informtaion? @Leucippus

Comment: @MaryStar The first three comments agree that there is not enough information. What is needed is: How many steps are taken per second/minute/hour ?

Comment: Ok!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: I propose not to think as mathematicians but as physicists or biomechanics. The following sites will give some insights:  http://healthyliving.azcentral.com/length-legs-walking-speed-10071.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preferred_walking_speed and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naismith%27s_rule and

Comment: I choose option B.